# Getting JSON response Android

Tags: android, json

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

try {
    StringEntity documentStringified = new StringEntity(Obj.toString());
    httpPost.setEntity(documentStringified);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.d("UnsupportedEncodingException", e.toString());
}

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("IOException", e.toString());
}
```

I am not able to get the `response`. How to print the response in `Logger or console.` `response.toString()` or `response.getEntity.toString()` does not work.

Should i set the Content-type as `"application/json"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general approach is:

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Moreover, you can check response code. Sometimes, requests fail.

```
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (status == 200) {
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());    
}
```

Comment: One last question, how do i set the content-type : 'application/json' to my http

Comment: For the request, you can use ```httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");```

Answer (score 1):

Get the `InputStream` out of the response, and then use a `Scanner` to consume its contents.

```
String responseContent = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

`useDelimiter("\\A")` means "the delimiter is the end of the stream", so `next()` consumes all of the content.